# Flutter TapBar Page white flicker on init

Tags: flutter, dart, tabbar, flutter-go-router

I am using a `TabBarView` in my app like this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          TabBarView(
            controller: _controller,
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            children: const [
              WishlistsView(),
              FriendsView(),
              EventsView(),
              InboxView(),
              ProfileView(),
            ],
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: BottomNavBar(
              initialIndex: widget.navBarOption.index,
              onPageChanged: (index) => _tap(context, index),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _tap(BuildContext context, int index) => context.go(
        '/home/${BottomNavBarOption.values[index].name}',
      );
```

Now the problem is that when I go on another page **the first time** there is a very short white screen before the page is actually displayed.

[Here](https://gofile.io/d/6s8ynl) is a ScreenVideo for a better understanding. This happens on both Web and iOS.

Why is that happening? Can I avoid that? As you can see the views are not very heavy.

All they have is basically a `SVGPicture.asset` :

```
class _WishlistsViewState extends State<WishlistsView>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: const [
          BackgroundImage(option: BackgroundImageOption.wishlists),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @YeasinSheikh what do you mean by `including`? and I dont use `GetX` for Navigation. I use `go_router`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Kaushik Chandru correctly pointed out: The `SVG` are the problem. They have to load first. To solve that issue, I used this really useful function `precachePicture` right before I actually call `runApp`:

```
for (BackgroundImageOption imageOption in BackgroundImageOption.values) {
  await precachePicture(
    ExactAssetPicture(
      SvgPicture.svgStringDecoderBuilder,
      imageOption.assetPath,
    ),
    null,
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is probably taking time to load svg on the first go and caching it for showing it later.. You can probably try OffStage Widget which should load the UI and just not display it.

```
class _WishlistsViewState extends State<WishlistsView>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Offstage(
      offStage: false,
       child: Stack(
        children: const [
          BackgroundImage(option: BackgroundImageOption.wishlists),
        ],
      ),
     ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: yes its the SVG, but the pictures about *4 KB* which is really not that much. At least thats my thought :D But I guess its too much for Flutter.... Using `Offstage` is not changing anything unfortunately :( Any other idea?